# Multiple lambda method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

It's possible to chain/concatenate what is done with elements in a lambda expression like this:

```
list.forEach(s -> {
        System.out.println(s.toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
});
```

Is there a way to do this also with method references? Something like this:

```
list.forEach({
    System.out::println(String::toLowerCase);
    System.out::println(String::toCase);
});
```

I know I could do this in four separate calls (which do also more, that is mutate the values):

```
list.replaceAll(String::toLowerCase);
list.forEach(System.out::println);
list.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I can't even do something easy like this:

```
list.forEach({
    System.out::println;
    System.out::println;
});
```

Comment: A method reference is an _expression_ which yields a reference-typed value and has no side-effects. Clearly there is no point in attempting to use such an expression as a statement in a block. And honestly, I have no idea why you would want that---do you just like seeing a double colon instead of a single dot in your code?

Comment: Isn't it all about sugar ;) It was said in an Oracle MOOC to use method reference as often as possible. But looking at the complexity this brings up I won't - just where it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

chaining is possible through default methods of the functional interfaces. But the "problem" is that there that the inference engine does not have enough information to determine that the left hand side is the same functional interface when you're returning the right hand side of the compositing expression.

To provide that information you either have to cast the statement:

```
  List<String> l = Collections.emptyList();
  l.forEach(((Consumer<String>)System.out::println).andThen(System.out::println));
```

Or assign it to a variable first:

```
  Consumer<String> cons = System.out::println;
  Collections.<String>emptyList().forEach(cons.andThen(System.out::println));
```

Alternatively you could also write static helper methods that do what you want

```
Collections.<String>emptyList().forEach(combine(System.out::println, System.out::println));

static <T> Consumer<T> combine(Consumer<T>... consumers) {
    // exercise left to the reader
}
```

Comment: This one is not working:
`list.forEach(((Consumer<String>)String::toUpperCase)
                .andThen(System.out::println));`

Comment: typechecks on my machine

Comment: So, any suggestion how to solve it and make it work?
It is just not making the words uppercase.

Comment: I answered how to chain, not how to solve the exact samples given. Look at the `Function` interface for other chaining methods.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't use method references as you have suggested. Method references are really just a syntactic replacement for a lambda expression. So that instead of:

```
text -> console.print(text)
```

You can avoid introducing an unnecessary variable and instead use

```
console::print
```

So when you mention that you can't do something such as:

```
list.forEach({
    System.out::println;
    System.out::println;
});
```

This is just a syntactic shortcut for

```
list.forEach({
    c -> System.out.println(c);
    c -> System.out.println(c);
});
```

This really makes no sense. There's no variable representing the item in the list (which would have to be outside the block) and the two 'statements' are lambda expressions with nothing to be applied to.

Method references are a pretty neat shortcut to avoid having an unnecessary variable but they are just a substitute for a more verbose lambda expression and can't be used as an independent statement in a block.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in converting

```
list.forEach(s -> {
    System.out.println(s.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
});
```

to

```
list.forEach({
    System.out::println(String::toLowerCase);
    System.out::println(String::toUpperCase);
});
```

as there is no win in clarity, the latter even consists of more characters than the former, if we use the same indention and insert the `Upper` you have left off the second variant. So why should we have such an alternative form?

Method reference have been invented as a feature allowing a dense syntax for a single method delegation, were declaring and referencing the parameters could really make a difference. Even replacing a sole `s->System.out.println(s)` with `System.out::println` is no that big win, but at least, there is some. Further, encoding the method reference at bytecode level can be more compact because the target method can be directly referenced just like the synthetic method holding a lambda expression’s code. For compound method references, there is no such compact form.

---

Since your desired operation consist of operations of different kinds, you may use the `Stream` API, which is intended to combine such operations:

```
list.stream().flatMap(s->Stream.of(s.toLowerCase(), s.toUpperCase()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

and if you want to include method references for everything, at all costs, you may do it the following way:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(s->Stream.<UnaryOperator<String>>of(String::toLowerCase, String::toUpperCase)
        .map(f->f.apply(s)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```